# jQuery $.get doesn't execute if returned data contains NaN

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, nan

In a Python Flask application, I am returning a JSON response that contains a NaN item:

```
@app.route('/update/')
def update():
    ...
    weight = float('nan')
    return jsonify(wt=weight) # weight is nan
```

In javascript for the page I have:

```
$.get( "/update", function( data ) {
    var wt = data['wt']
    // do something with wt
    ....
}
```

When the javascript $.get function is called, the function never executes if wt is NaN. If `wt` is a string or a number (float) it works just fine. The JSON response from python  reads:

```
{..., 'response': { "wt": NAN }}
```

Since javascript understands NaNs, why is the function failing to execute if wt is NaN? No error is given in the browser console, and python appears to return the response just fine as well.

Comment: `NAN` != `NaN`.  did you typo the case on that `A`?

Comment: NaN is not valid JSON the last time I checked, it will be converted to null. `JSON.stringify({ y : NaN });` --> `"{"y":null}"`

Comment: `json.dumps('wt': weight})` yields: `'{"wt": NaN}'` in python 2.7x. I did mistype the NAN. The json response is the same as this comment.